# Emacs: How to redefine Ctrl-Enter when CUA-mode is enabled?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, cua-mode

If **cua-mode** is enabled, redefining **Ctrl-Enter** does not works as expected and always runs **cua-set-rectangle-mark** function. In the code below you can see that I also defined **Alt-Enter** to my function, just for testing, and it runs fine. But I wish to left **Alt-Enter** to **cua-set-rectangle-mark** because I prefer to use **Ctrl-Enter** to call my function that creates a line below the current line. What is wrong?

```
(cua-mode t)
(defun vscode-insert-line-below()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (newline-and-indent))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") 'vscode-insert-line-below)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<return>") 'vscode-insert-line-below)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```lisp
(cua-mode t)
(defun vscode-insert-line-below()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (newline-and-indent))
(define-key cua-global-keymap (kbd "<C-return>") 'vscode-insert-line-below)
```

(You can use either `(kbd "<C-return>")` or `(kbd "C-<return>")`, but I like to use the form that `C-h k` shows me.)

When you are in `cua-mode` the local keymap is `cua-global-keymap`, and its bindings override the same global bindings.

I found that map by doing `C-h k C-RET` in `cua-mode`. It told me:

> `<C-return>` runs the command `cua-set-rectangle-mark` (found in
>   `cua-global-keymap`), which is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function
>   in `cua-rect.el`.
>
> It is bound to `<C-return>`.
>
> [Arg list not available until function definition is loaded.]
>
> Start rectangle at mouse click position.

Comment: It worked. Thank you Drew. I am just beginning with Emacs and Emacs Lisp. It is still mysterious to me :-)